# Is this node replacement code reasonable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yMSHa/ (Note: Real code uses JQuery 1.4.1)

HTML:

```
<div data-name="action" data-id="1">Do It A 1</div>
<div data-name="action" data-id="2">Do It A 2</div>
<div data-name="action" data-id="3">Do It A 3</div>
<div data-name="action" data-id="4">Do It A 4</div>
<div data-name="action" data-id="5">Do It A 5</div>
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="DoIt2">Do It B</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var RepDiv = $('#DoIt2');
var OldDiv = null;

$('div[data-name="action"]').each(function (i, f) {
    var actionid = $(f).attr('data-id');
    if (actionid) {
        $(f).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        var OnClick = function () {
            if (OldDiv) {
                RepDiv.replaceWith(OldDiv);
                OldDiv.click(OnClick);
            }
            OldDiv = $(this).replaceWith(RepDiv);
        };
        $(f).click(OnClick);
    }
});
```

Below is some simple JavaScript which replaces one node at a time when that node is clicked.  The idea behind this code is that a user can click on a node for that node to be expanded with more options.

I'm looking for a general review.  My main concern is whether this code is written properly in terms of good practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a once over;

- `i` and `f`, even for `forEach` are not very good names, pick something more meaningful.
- if `data-id` is the action id, perhaps you could have gotten/set it with `$().data('actionId')` ?
- The way your replacement function uses `OldDiv` and `RepDiv` smells like global variable abuse
- Consider using smallCamelCase, `actionid` -> `actionId`, `OldDiv` -> `oldDiv`
- Consider caching `$(f)`, since you access it several times ( `var $f = $(f);` and then only access `$f` )
- This : `$(f).css('cursor', 'pointer');` really belongs in .css file

Other than that, your code looks okay to me.

Comment: I resolved the global variable concerns by wrapping the code in a function (i.e., `var GlobalWrapper = function() {/*My Code*/}();`).  Setting `data-id` with `.data()` is a bit more difficult than setting it in an attribute, as divs are generated by an asp.net repeater that looks something like `<div data-id = '<%=Data.ID%>'>`.  The interesting thing about `$(f).css('cursor', 'pointer');` is that it means the links don't look clickable until the events are loaded.  I'm not sure if that should be considered a good thing.